# Returning arraylist and using in different class

Tags: java, arraylist, return

I am trying to return an arraylist from this method

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/** The class reader read the file 2RainfallDataLanc.txt and stores is as an ArrayList. 
 * It also parses the variables within the file by white spaces, making variables accessible.
 *
 */
public class reader {

    public ArrayList<String[]> getRows(){

    try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("2RainfallDataLanc.txt"));
            String line = null;
            ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();

            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) 
            {String[] row = line.split("\\s+");
            rows.add(row);

                }
            for (String[] row : rows) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
                return rows;
                }   

} catch (IOException e) {
}
    return null;
}
}
```

As I wish to use it in another class. The second class currently looks like this :

```
public class mean extends reader{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    reader newarray = new reader();

}

}
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Whenever I try to return rows I get an error message saying that void methods cannot return a value.

Comment: The only method declaration I see is your `main` method.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't create a method in your `reader` object with which to return something from.  Create a method signature like the following:

```
public ArrayList<String[]> getRows() {
    // Rest of your code here.
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have added in the method as you have suggested but the only return typed it allows me is null otherwise comes up with error messages. Is this what I want? Would appreciate if you could look at updated code.

Comment: `null` is a reference to nothing, which is acceptable when returning objects (which are references to something).  However, bear in mind that if you're relying on the existence of the ArrayList, then you would want to *throw* an exception, rather than return `null`.

Comment: When trying to access the first element of the arraylist in the class mean by newarray[1] I get an error message saying The type of the expression must be an array type but it is resolved to reader. Since I am returning the arraylist, why does it say that?

Comment: @user1408525: You have to store the result of your function in the same datatype that its signature calls for - so you'd need to instantiate an `ArrayList<String[]>` somewhere in main.  Also, the first element is at position 0, not 1.